Нашёл вот такой код на C++. не понимаю 10 строку, как работает && в ней?
Вот код:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void solve() {
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int ok = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        ok = ok && s[i] == s[n - i - 1]; // вот тут не понимаю
    puts(ok && k * 2 < n ? "YES" : "NO");
}

int main() {
    int t; cin >> t;
    while(t--) {
        solve();
    }
}


А в чем непонимание? Вы в целом знаете что такое &&?

знаю только что он в условиях исползуеться

ok = ok && s[i] == s[n - i - 1]

Если ok равно false, то оно таковым и останется, если true, то станет результатом сравнения s[i] == s[n - i - 1].
Правда, я бы его переписал как
if ((ok = ok && s[i] == s[n - i - 1]) == false) break;

Просто нет смысла проверять дальше, если ok стало равно false.

а, теперь понял, спасибо

По сути, ok сбрасывается в 0, если есть хоть одно несовпадение

== false ?!?!?!

@StanislavVolodarskiy Только для вас: if (!(ok = ok && s[i] == s[n - i - 1])) break; :) Выбрал проверку с помощью равенства из дидактических соображений :) Вы об этом?

А я бы этот ok = s[i] == s[n - i - 1]) вообще в условие цикла загнал ...

Тут идёт сравнение условий, то есть && - логическое И.
Условие будет верным если: ok = ok (Тут скорее всего ошибка, идёт присваивание)
И условие s[i] == s[n - i - 1];

так в том то и дело, что код отлично работает, и тут ошибки нет, поэтому я и не понимаю

Здесь нет условия, это не if, а присваивание...

&& - логическое И,
&& - (конъюнкция, логическое умножение)
Возвращает true, если оба операнда не равны false. Возвращает false, если хотя бы один операнд равен false.
Справочник по языку С++
